# Scrapy - how to save the file generated via POST submission

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

While submitting a form to the cboe.com website, it sends a file that need to be saved to disk and then re-directs to the same form page.

How do I save the file that is returned using Scrapy? I have below code but it is not able to get a handle to the file as its getting redirected.

```
import scrapy

class FileDownload(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Test'
    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formdata={'txtTicker': 'AAPL'},
                callback=self.after_download
        )
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            'http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quote-table-download',
            meta = {
              'dont_redirect': True,
               'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]
            }
        )
    def after_download(self, response):
        if(response is None):
            print("--------Empty response for download----------")
        else:
            print(response)
        return
```

log snippet of scrapy

2020-06-06 19:15:02 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quote-table-download> (referer: None)
2020-06-06 19:15:14 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-06-06 19:18:22 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

**2020-06-06 19:18:27 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quotedata.dat> from http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quote-table-download>
2020-06-06 19:25:54 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-06-06 19:25:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quote-table-download> from http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quotedata.dat>
2020-06-06 19:25:55 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quote-table-download> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)**

2020-06-06 19:25:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-06-06 19:25:55 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:

http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/quotedata.dat is data file that I need to save.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a wrong field name (`txtTicker`):

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                'ctl00$ContentTop$C005$txtTicker': 'AAPL',
                'ctl00$ContentTop$C005$cmdSubmit': 'Download',
            },
            callback=self.after_download
    )
```